# HTML Navigation anchor should not jump to the Top of the Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create a website and have a problem with the "anchor" navigation.
At the top of the page there is a fixed Header. When you scroll the main part disapears under the Header.

Now i have on the left side a navigation, to jump to different titles.
But with the "anchor" function, the title always jumps to far. he already disapears under the header.
Is there a posibility to jump just close to the top?

here is a fiddle example.

```
<div class="header">Header <br> <br> <a href="#Title2">Title2</a></div>
<div class="main">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <h1 id="Title2">Title 2</h1> 
</div>

.header{
width:500px;
height:100px;
background-color: red;
position:fixed;

}
.main {
padding-top: 100px;
width:500px;
height:1000px;
background-color:lightblue;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BLrUG/

click the "Title2" link, to see the problem.

thx BBallBoy

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is in your fiddle?? i only tried changing the width and height to 100% in the .main but , i dont understand your problem here

Comment: click the "Title2" link.

Comment: if you make the field larger in jsfiddle there will be no scroll bar. its automatically this way. if you add more titles you will see it jumps to the title directly but because the page is so short he jumps only that far. I could be wrong but as far as I know its supposed to be this way

Comment: no the problem is, when you click the link the "Title2" is hidden behind the header. But i want the "Title2" right under the header...

Comment: In Jsfiddle you wont be able to see what you see but i understand your  problem. but i dont think i can help you with this problem I thinks it automatically does that. You cant say that the page has to go 100px to the bottom so that the title comes perfect underneath the header.

Comment: I cant help your any further in this question , sorry.

Comment: np thx, i will try it with a different container under the header, thx for the idea :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BLrUG/3/

Changed the height

Comment: in your fiddle, the problem is just solved for this special height, if my content has a diffrent size or the window is smaller, it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

position fixed acts like absolute ... other elements dont know for the excisting of this header and they go over/under it.ur code is running right u need to add this :

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
```

to clear the spaceses and ur page will look fine

maybe u are searching for this [Jquery funcs](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/):

Comment: sry but i don't understand which container should have this attributs.
PS: i now the header has no affect to other <div>, but is there a solution, not to jump so close to the top?

Comment: u must use JQuery to make it know and it must scroll from the HEADER not from the body i'm not that good in Jquery so i will leave it to u to understand it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript call to scroll to the element but fix the offset a bit so it isn't covered by the header.

```
function scrollTo(id) {
    var offset = 0;

    //Get element
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);

    //Determine offset  
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            offset += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    //Account for header
    offset -= 120;

    window.scroll(0, offset);
}
```

Then instead of using the ID in the anchor you pass it to the function

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:scrollTo('Title2');">Title2</a>
```

You'll need to play around with the offset fix to find the best value. You may also want to make it a parameter to the function to make it more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

use top position in header class

```
 top:0px;
```

and use div for both title paragraphs and set top margin for both para div .